# php chdir() direct to home directory

Tags: php

How do i change the directory in php :
I tried this :

```
chdir('\');
```

But this doesnt changes the directory.
I am using php-cli

I will prefer a cross platform solution(i.e. common for windows , linux , mac)

Comment: That shouldn't even do anything, because `\ ` is an escape character and by writing `\'` you're escaping the apostrophe, not closing the string.

Comment: But it doesnt gives an syntax error it happens when i do this "\"

Comment: As a side note: In *nix environments it could be that you can't access anything outside the defined webserver-serv-directory (like `/var/www/`. I'm not sure how this is handled on Windows, though.

Comment: And even if i do this "\"" Still doesnt does any good to me

Comment: @kritya: No syntax error? I get this: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting ')'`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change to home directory, you can use:

```
chdir($_SERVER['HOMEPATH']);
```

It's even cross-platform this way.

**EDIT:**

If you mean "home directory" as top directory on drive, you can use:

```
chdir($_SERVER['HOMEDRIVE']);
```

Answer (score 1):

- http://alanhogan.com/tips/php/directory-separator-not-necessary

> **As long as you use the forward slash, “/”, you’ll be OK. Windows doesn’t mind it, and it’s best for *nix operating systems.**

Based on the above:

```
 chdir('/'); 
 // current directory
 echo getcwd() . "\n";
```

Do you see errors anywhere?

> Warning: chdir() [function.chdir]: Permission denied (errno 13)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (stristr (PHP_OS, 'Win')) { 
   chdir('C:\\');
} elseif (stristr (PHP_OS, 'Lin')) { 
   chdir('/');
} else {
    chdir($_SERVER['HOMEPATH']);

    //i am not sure what does MAC use as its root
}
```

try this one. By single \ you're escaping single quote

Comment: Still an error : PHP Warning:  chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2) in /var/www/pbot/index.php on line 10

Comment: answer edited again. You're on linux. Linux uses ../ to get to previous directory

Comment: base directory of pbot or / ?

Comment: Maybe i did some error in explaining i want to go to dir '/' if using linux or if using windows for eg 'C:'